# Cannot find Jupyter Notebook server on port 8888 (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, docker, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to run a Docker container as a Jupyter Notebook on Windows 10. As shown in the screen grab, the notebook appears to be running on localhost:8888, but my browsers (Chrome and Edge) return a 'connection refused' error. I've disabled my firewall (temporarily), but that didn't help. Also, netstat does not list the port as being in use. Any idea what's going on?

[image: Screengrab showing Docker running]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

`docker run -p 8888:8888 -it simonwalkersamuel/bloch_tf:latest`

`-p 8888:8888` will map container port 8888 to host port 8888.

Comment: That worked, many thanks. Not sure why I didn't need to do this on my Windows laptop...? (But did have to on my workstation)

Comment: Thats cool , Just accept the answer so we can help others too.

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR** make sure you mapped the ports using `-p 8888:8888`. If didn't work, try `192.168.99.100:8888` instead of `localhost:8888`.

**Situation:**
I had a slightly different problem: Although I mapped the ports using `-p 8888:8888`, I still see the connection error when I try to reach `localhost:8888` in all browsers. The firewall is checked and seems OK. It was very confusing because exactly same docker image works on my other Win 10 laptop at work.

**Solution:**
I have two slightly different Win 10 on my laptops. The one that has connection difficulty runs a ***Win 10 Home*** whereas the other one has a ***Win 10 Professional***. This means, the problematic laptop only runs Docker Tools not the conventional Docker CE. Therefore, it maps communicates with the OS using `192.168.99.100` IP not the usual `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`. So, instead of `localhost:8888` just used `192.168.99.100:8888` and it worked.

**Confession!**
I usually use my work laptop for running Jupyter on docker. Therefore, I did not pay enough attention to the welcome message of Docker Quickstart Terminal which clearly says `docker is configured to use the default machine with IP 192.168.99.100`. Hopefully, this post helps other too busy (aka careless!) people like me!

---

Since both laptops have very similar apps installed, I doubt anything rather than the Docker app itself causes the difference in IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following commands:

```
run these two command
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install --upgrade jupyter
```